# Why does my digit_sum only loop once for Python Code Academy lesson?

Tags: python, while-loop

My code (trying to write a code to return the sum of all the digits n, ex if n=1234, return 10):

```
def digit_sum(n):
  summation=0
  while n > 0:
      digit=n%10
      summation=n//(10)
      summation=summation+digit
      print n
      return summation


print digit_sum(244)
```

This code will return 244 and then below 28, but does not complete the final step and return 10. Do you know why the while loop cuts off?

Comment: Returning in loops is rarely a good idea

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. `return` statement is part of while loop that's the reason while loop is executing only once
2. value of `n` is not reducing so it will run forever as `while n > 0` so updated it with `n=n//10` now it will be reduced

**code:**

```
def digit_sum(n):
    summation=0
    while n > 0:
        digit=n%10
        n=n//(10)
        summation=summation+digit
        # print n
    return summation

print digit_sum(244)
```

**output:**

```
10
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful.